# Solvent for Terephthalic Acid TLC

Tags: chromatography

We're trying to do thin layer chromatography to assess the purity of Terephthalic Acid. So far we have tried DMF, and Water of different pH values. Does anybody know a better solvent or combination?

Comment: I presume this is on silica plates, have you tried chloroform/MeOH, or n-BuOH/water/acetic acid?

Comment: Merck has published a Separation of Terephthalic acid and Reaction Products data sheet at https://www.google.com/search?q=chromatography+of+terephthalic+acid&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsYOCTterkWy3HuBIy-log_KoLr1uA:1652382873353&ei=mVx9YoeWFfSzkvQPwoqX8AM&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjHxsvx1dr3AhX0mYQIHULFBT4Q8NMDegQIARBM&biw=1146&bih=836&dpr=1  which specifies CH3OH/CH3CN/H2O (20/30/50) on Silica Gel 60 RP-18 WF254s.